# C# Drawing a Bitmap on a certain point in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, picturebox, point

I currently have a `Bitmap` image. I need to place this image at a certain coordinate inside a `PictureBox`. Specifically, I'm looking to place it 5 pixels from the top and 5 pixels from the left. The bitmap will be of different lengths, so I want the starting point to always start drawing the `Bitmap` at this specific point.

As an example, here are two "Bitmaps" that both start at the coordinate 5,5, with different lengths. Imagine the Gray is the `PictureBox`:

[image] [image]

I've tried something like passing in a `PictureBox` and using graphics to draw the bitmap:

```
private void setQuantity(PictureBox pb, int quantity) {

    Graphics g = pb.CreateGraphics();

    g.DrawImage(iqc.createQuantityImage(quantity), 0, 0);

    g.Dispose();

}
```

`iqc.createQuantityImage() returns a Bitmap`

But this doesn't seem to draw anything. I have also changed the x and y and nothing changes.

I'd like to be able to specify the exact coordinate or point inside the `PictureBox` if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your picturebox also have a picture set to it?

Comment: It has a `BackgroundImage` set, but not an `Image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw image in PictureBox at any location by adding an event handler to its Paint method as follows;

```
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_myBitmap, new Point(5, 5));    //Here new Point(x,y) determines location in pictureBox where you want to draw the bitmap.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the way. Can you explain or point me to docs which explain what tiggers the PictureBox_Paint() function? I see why the drawing works, but not when the function is called.

Comment: Paint event is called when that control needs to be redrawn. For ex. when form or control is resized, Refresh is called or Invalidate is called on control. [This](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/draw-in-a-paint-event-handler-in-c/) link provides the explanation for it.